# Undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, glibc, libc, gsl

I am installing a package (on Ubuntu 20.04) and get the following errors:

```
loslib.c:(.text+0x2b0): warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/home/satadru/anaconda3/envs/sedona/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/satadru/anaconda3/envs/sedona/lib/./libgfortran.so.4: undefined reference to `secure_getenv@GLIBC_2.17'
/home/satadru/anaconda3/envs/sedona/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/satadru/anaconda3/envs/sedona/lib/./libgfortran.so.4: undefined reference to `clock_gettime@GLIBC_2.17'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The issue was not resolved eben after I installed 'libgfortran' using conda.

I suppose, my `GLIBC` version is 2.31 as `ldd --version` prints:

```
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.9) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

I have no clue how to solve this. I created a new conda environment to compile this code. Any help will highly appriciated.